# Trigonometry question using complex numbers on the complex plane

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I am not quite sure what this is asking, I tried to square these numbers and then convert into radians but it was not right. I am only used to graphing the absolute value of complex numbers.

**Let $z=−5−5\sqrt{3i}$**

1. When z is graphed in the complex plane, what radian angle does it make with the positive $x$-axis?
2. What radian angles do $z^2$, $z^3$, and $z^4$ make with the positive $x$-axis? *You may want to use your calculator to compute the powers of $z$.*
3. For what values of $n$ does $z^n$ lie on the positive x-axis?

Comment: complex "plane"

Comment: You can represent $a+bi$ in the 2D plane by $x$-coordinate $a$ and $y$-coordinate $b$.  Then draw a line from the origin to the point $(a,b)$.  The angle that line makes with the $x$-axis is the "radian angle" they are looking for.

Comment: If you right the complex numbers as the product of module and phase you can easily found the answer to your questions.

Comment: So then after graphing it and assuming that it is a 30-60-90 triangle, would the answer to the first question be pi/3? @GregoryGrant

Comment: Yes but be careful, the point is in the 3rd quadrant.

Comment: Also, if $z$ has $r$ radians, then conveniently $z^2$ has $2r$ radians, $z^3$ has $3r$ radians, etc.. That makes part 2 easy once you have part one.

Comment: So since it is in the 3rd quadrant, _z_ is 4pi/3, so are you saying to find the rest, I would just multiply that by 2, 3, and so on? @GregoryGrant

Comment: @Shayla Yes, that is exactly correct.  Pretty convenient isn't it?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes it is! so then how would I be able to find out what values of $n$ does $z^n$ lie on the positive x-axis?

Comment: Well you basically need $n\cdot 4\pi/3$ to be equal to a multiple of $2\pi$ right?  So for example $n=0$, $n=3$, $n=6$, etc...

Comment: @GregoryGrant I am still a little confused, so how would I phrase that is needs to be a multiple of 2pi in an equation? would it be 2pik?

Comment: You need $n\cdot 4\pi/3=2\pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.  Thus $n=3k/2$.  That's only an integer if $2$ divides $k$ and then $n$ is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I submitted the answer to my webworks and for the third question it accepted "3(k-1)" and as for the second questions it did not accept the 2r answers, any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did you format the answer to part two?

Answer (score 0):

$$\arg(-5-5\sqrt3\,i)=\arctan\frac{-5\sqrt3}{-5}=\arctan\sqrt3=\frac\pi3\pm k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Since $\;-5-5\sqrt3\,i\;$ is in the third quadrant, it **must** be its argument is $\;\dfrac\pi3+\pi=\dfrac{4\pi}3\;$ (of course, this is defined *only* up to multiples of $\;2\pi i\;$ )